# Powershell deletion script for files with recurring date extension like .20181104, 20181105 etc

Tags: powershell, scripting

All,

This is my script to delete log files on one of our PTV servers. the issue here is that the logs files have been named in a way that shows different date extensions like "blah.log.20181102", "blah.log.20181103"

My dilemma is how to remove files with different dates at the end. I was want to get the number of files deleted so I am using the measure-object but it keeps giving me a count of "0" even after deletion. Below is my script:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$path = 'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello1'
$path = 'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello2'
$path = 'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello3'

Get-Childitem -Path @(
    'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello1\*'
    'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello2\*'
    'C:\Users\uyr2f3d\Downloads\Hello3\*'
) -Include '*.tmp', '*.log' -Force -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
    Remove-Item | ForEach-Object { $_ }

Measure-Object
Get-Date
Read-Host -Prompt 'The files have been deleted successfully'
```

I want a prompt showing number of files deleted and when it was deleted. That is what the read-host prompt is for. I am open to simplifying and making this query better since its also deleting files from 3 different folders.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you mean by "when it was deleted" ... it was deleted when the script was run. [*grin*]

this will accept a list of files, parse the extension for the date, compare the age in days to the cutoff age, and then delete or not as per the test. it then shows the total count and the deleted count.

```
# save the old InfoPref
$OldInfoPref = $InformationPreference
# enable Info output
$InformationPreference = 'Continue'

# fake reading in a list of files
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem
$FileList = @(
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'One.log.20180101'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Two.log.20180202'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Three.log.20180303'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Four.log.20180404'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Five.log.20180505'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Ten.log.20181010'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Nine.log.20180909'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Eight.log.20180808'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Eleven.log.20181111'
    )

$MaxDaysOld = 30
$Today = (Get-Date).Date

$DeletedFileList = foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $DaysOld = ($Today - [datetime]::ParseExact($FL_Item.Extension.Trim('.'), 'yyyyMMdd', $Null)).Days
    if ($DaysOld -gt $MaxDaysOld)
        {
        Write-Information ('The file named {0} is too old [{1} days].' -f $FL_Item.Name, $DaysOld)
        Write-Information '    ----- The file would be deleted -----.'
        Write-Information ''

        # put your delete command on the next line


        # send the deleted file name to the deleted file collection
        $FL_Item
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Information ('The file named {0} is only {1} days old.' -f $FL_Item.Name, $DaysOld)
        Write-Information '    The file would NOT be deleted.'
        Write-Information ''
        }
    }

'=' * 50
'Total file count   = {0}' -f $FileList.Count
'Deleted file count = {0}' -f $DeletedFileList.Count

# restore the old InfoPref
$InformationPreference = $OldInfoPref
```

output ...

```
The file named One.log.20180101 is too old [317 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Two.log.20180202 is too old [285 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Three.log.20180303 is too old [256 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Four.log.20180404 is too old [224 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Five.log.20180505 is too old [193 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Ten.log.20181010 is too old [35 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Nine.log.20180909 is too old [66 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Eight.log.20180808 is too old [98 days].
    ----- The file would be deleted -----.

The file named Eleven.log.20181111 is only 3 days old.
    The file would NOT be deleted.

==================================================
Total file count   = 9
Deleted file count = 8
```